# Clearing a TextBox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have webpage where there is textbox with some default value. I have to clear that value from the textbox. I have two options:

```
textbox.text="";
```

or

```
textbox.text.remove(0,length);
```

Which one should I use? Does it make any impact on page performance (there are many textboxes placed on my page)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best way to do this is

```
textbox.text = string.Empty;
```

**Also remember that string type is immutable!**

Comment: Thank you very much,

Does it make any impact of being a immutable

Comment: Immutability does not affect much in your case. But Yes immutability has great impact. Immutable objects upon assignment are replicated by recreation and not copied.

Answer (score 9):

It makes no difference - do what is most readable for you and your colleagues.

Many prefer to use `string.Empty`.

Comment: @John please - we both know this is beyond trivial.

Comment: @Rex: maybe it's too early in the morning for me, but what do you mean?

Comment: @John the *actual* difference between the two is meaningless. Of course a method call is not the same as assignment, but only if you're counting clock cycles.

Comment: @Rex: the OP said, "Does it make any impact on page performance because there are many textbox placed in page.", so I think to say it makes no difference is not correct.

Comment: @John if you can get enough textboxes on the page that you can measure the difference in milliseconds, I'll be impressed.

Comment: Thanks Rex and Jhon,

Can you more focus on the method call and assignment. It create curiosity for more. I will be thankfull if you have any link/ document which is more focused on c# best coding practices.

Comment: @Hemant I strongly encourage you to not worry about it. Focus on known performance bottlenecks like O(n^x) operations, network and disk I/O. The absolute last thing in the world you need to worry about is the weight of a method call.

Answer (score 3):

1. The performance difference between the two options will be too small to measure, most likely.
2. `TextBox.Text = String.Empty;` is a lot more readable. It clearly states what you're trying to do: "set the text property of this text box to an empty string".

I recommend you go with the assignment, as it is both faster, and much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you mean clear the value with javascript when a user clicks int the box? If so, it won't make any difference to performance.

I use jQuery in most pages, so I just hook up this function to clear default values onClick, using the ClientId of the textbox:

```
$('#ctl00_TextBox').click(function() { $('#ctl00_TextBox').val('');
```

If you mean clear it in codebehind use this:

```
yourTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox.text="";
```

or

```
 foreach (var item in Page.Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)item).Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The impact on performance will be minimal even with hundreds/thousands of calls, however

```
textbox.text = "";
```

should in theory be very slightly quicker, since you're just assigning a new value rather than processing the string (as .Remove does)

The best way to do this would be to do

```
textbox.text = String.Empty;
```

**Update:** if you're counting clock-cycles, String.Empty will actually execute faster as well, because it doesn't create a new object, whereas "" will create a new String object.

**However, you should really not be too concerned about this, there aren't many ways to set a string to empty that will cause performance issues! You should use whichever is the most readable...**

Comment: Why is string.Empty better than ""? "" is interned and is identical to string.Emtpy. Object.ReferenceEquals(string.Empty, "") will return true.

Comment: The first bit of your answer is correct, but I'm not too sure about the rest. Maybe just stick with what you're sure of?

Comment: Yes, it may be interned, but Brad Adams implies this is not necessarily the case... http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx So String.Empty is safer if we're really after these minuscule optimisations. Maybe the compiler does/could/should optimise this? I haven't looked at the IL to check...