# How to make a textbox empty in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox (txtbox1) which has some value in it. I want to empty the value of textbox. Is that possible in code behind? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing a TextBox in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957763/clearing-a-textbox-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well:

```
txtbox1.Text = "";
```

should do it.

(Note that I generally prefer `""` to `string.Empty` in terms of readability. Use whichever you prefer. Ignore any talk about the performance differences between them - most articles I've seen on this are out of date, and any performance difference there *might* be will be entirely insignificant.)

Comment: Oops I was trying many things like txtbox1.Text.Remove(), txtbox1.Trim, etc. Thank you Jon! :)

Comment: I used to agree with "" over String.Empty. Until I started doing some memory profiling and realized how many hundreds of thousands of instances of an empty string you can end up creating on a heavily used web application. From a performance perspective, it probably doesn't matter, but from a memory perspective, I now favor String.Empty.

Comment: @NerdFury: Um, you don't end up with *any* extra strings by using "". String literals are *guaranteed* to be interned in C#. I don't know what your profiling was finding, but it *wasn't* multiple strings generated from string literals.

Comment: Ok, you win again. The massive number of empty strings was probably the result of string manipulations that resulted in empty strings. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 9):

```
txtbox1.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

use        `textbox1.Text = null;`
you can also use `textBox1.Text = "";`

if you want to put strings in the future  `textBox1.Text = string.Empty;`